# Video/3gpp in MediaPlayer on device

Tags: codenameone

I am building a chat app. I am trying to add support for videos.

the URL for the video is https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC5c869939f6863233a73ac697207c3697/Messages/MMf01fb40e39c41feafbc0967590f161e8/Media/MEbd3e3d9a0c2be95e01de341889e8cfbb

```
Container container = new Container(new BorderLayout());
Media video = com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(url, true); // url is the url above
video.setNativePlayerMode(true);
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(video);

//place the media player in the container
container.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mp);
Component component = Container.encloseIn(new FlowLayout(Container.RIGHT), container);
```

When I make a debug build and put this on my iPhone, I just get a black box where I would expect the video player to be.

In the simulator, I got playback controls, but no video either.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work on the device although the simulator might be a bit flaky:

```
Form hi = new Form("Player", new BorderLayout());
try {
    Media video = MediaManager.createMedia("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC5c869939f6863233a73ac697207c3697/Messages/MMf01fb40e39c41feafbc0967590f161e8/Media/MEbd3e3d9a0c2be95e01de341889e8cfbb", true); 
    hi.add(CENTER, video.getVideoComponent());
    video.setNativePlayerMode(true);
    hi.show();
    hi.addShowListener(e -> video.play());
} catch(IOException err) {
    Log.e(err);
    hi.add(CENTER, "Failed to load video");
    hi.show();
}
```

Notice a few things:

1. the simulator doesn't support HTTPS URL's for media due to limitations of JavaFX. It doesn't support some video stream types and might not support 3gp properly
2. iOS requires an HTTPS URL
3. I placed the video component in the center of the border layout in a form. This forces a specific size for the video which is important.

Comment: how can it be done in a container   Container placeholder2 = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
        placeholder2.setUIID("movieplaceholder");
        Button addToCartbtn2 = new Button("Add to cart");

        placeholder2.addAll(new Label("A Game of Thrones"), addToCartbtn2);

        Container row1 = GridLayout.encloseIn(2, placeholder1, placeholder2);

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to the question?

Comment: I want to create video placeholders in a "GridLayout.encloseIn(2, placeholder1, placeholder2);" for my video API like that of a youtube app

Comment: At the layout stage we don't know the size of the layout so video won't work well in a different layout out of the box. It will only work if you explicitly set the preferred size.

Answer (score 0):

3gp is not supported. I convert the video to mp4 and supply the url to that file to the Media Manager and it works fine.